# Show that $\mathbb{E}_\xi \left[(\pi-\theta_\xi)\cos\theta_\xi+\sin\theta_\xi\right] > 1$ when $\xi$ has sufficiently large variance

Tags: normal-distribution, polar-coordinates, expected-value

Let $v, w \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and denote $\theta = \angle(v, w) = \arccos \frac{v^\top w}{\lVert v \rVert_2 \lVert w \rVert_2} \in [0, \pi]$. Let $\xi \sim N(0, \sigma^2 I)$ be a Gaussian random vector in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Denote $\theta_\xi = \angle(v, w+\xi)$.

I empirically find that $$\mathbb{E}_\xi \left[(\pi-\theta_\xi)\cos\theta_\xi+\sin\theta_\xi\right]$$ is monotone w.r.t $\theta$, and for a sufficiently large $\sigma^2$, it is larger than 1 (approximately $1+O(\frac{1}{d})$) for all $\theta$.

I am stuck at finding theoretical justifications of such results. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that

\begin{align*}
\theta_\xi
\stackrel{d}{=} \angle (v, \sigma^{-1}w + \xi_1),
\end{align*}

where $\xi_1 \stackrel{d}{=} \sigma^{-1}\xi \sim \mathcal{N}(0,I)$. As $\sigma\to\infty$, this converges in distribution to $\angle(v, \xi_1)$. Since $\xi_1/\|\xi_1\|$ is uniformly distributed over the unit sphere $S^{d-1}$, the limiting distribution has density

\begin{align*}
f(\theta) := \frac{\Gamma(\frac{d}{2})}{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(\frac{d-1}{2})}\sin^{d-2}\theta \mathbf{1}_{[0,\pi]}{\theta}
\end{align*}

and hence

\begin{align*}
\lim_{\sigma\to\infty} \mathbb{E}\left[(\pi-\theta_\xi)\cos\theta_\xi+\sin\theta_\xi\right]
&= \int_{0}^{\pi} \left[ (\pi - \theta)\cos\theta + \sin\theta \right] f(\theta) \, d\theta \\
&= \frac{\Gamma(\frac{d}{2})\Gamma(\frac{d+2}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{d+1}{2})} \\
&= 1 + \frac{1}{2d} + \frac{1}{8d^2} + \cdots \quad \text{as } d \to \infty.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you for your answer! In fact, I want to find the minimum value of $\sigma$ that could guarantee this expectation is larger than 1 for all $\theta$. Do you have any idea about that?